# How to remove old value and update with a new one using SharedPreferences flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I am making a trivia app, I have three functions that load the counter, the second one increments the counter with a score value and the third unload the counter. load and increment functions are called in initState so that the score is incremented and displayed to the user on another screen. However, I am having difficulty removing the old score from the counter and updating it with a new score when the user restarts the game. Need help, Thanks

below is the code.

1 screen

```
class ResultScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  int score;

  // static Future init() async {
  //   prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  // }

  ResultScreen(this.score, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ResultScreenState createState() => _ResultScreenState();
}

class _ResultScreenState extends State<ResultScreen> {
  int score1 = 0;
  // String _haveStarted = '';
  // bool Restart = false;

  void loadCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      score1 = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0);
    });
  }

  void unloadCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.remove('counter');
  }

  void _incrementCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    setState(() {
      score1 = ((prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + widget.score);
      prefs.setInt('counter', score1);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    loadCounter();
    _incrementCounter();
  }
```

2nd screen code to display result

```
  const cardView1({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<cardView1> createState() => _cardView1State();
}

class _cardView1State extends State<cardView1> {
  int score1 = 0;

  void loadCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      score1 = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0);
    });
  }

  // void _incrementCounter() async {
  //   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  //   setState(() {
  //     score1 = ((prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + widget.score);
  //     prefs.setInt('counter', score1);
  //   });
  // }

  void unloadCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.remove('counter');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadCounter();
    // unloadCounter();

    ///whatever you want to run on page build
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 250,
      // (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 90) / 2,
      height: 170,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 15,
        bottom: 15,
        top: 15,
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        color: Colors.white,
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage("assets/piliers.png"),
        ),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            blurRadius: 3,
            offset: Offset(5, 5),
            color: color.AppColor.gradientSecond.withOpacity(0.1),
          ),
          BoxShadow(
            blurRadius: 3,
            offset: Offset(-5, -5),
            color: color.AppColor.gradientSecond.withOpacity(0.1),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Center(
          child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
        child: Container(
          height: 28.83,
          width: 50,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.orangeAccent,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topRight: Radius.circular(20), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
            //border: Border.all(color: color.AppColor.setsColor),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              "$score1",
              style:
                  TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Good question however I'm not able to actually understand what you mean by "However, I am having difficulty"... What difficulty is it that you're facing? Is it a specific issue? Could you be more specific as what the problem that you are facing actually is?

Comment: Excuse me for the late reply and thank you for your time... As for the challenge I am facing. The function " _incrementCounter()" increment the score to the existing score or int value in shared preferences Ex: 2(score in Sp) + 5 (new score )= 7 (current score), and the function "loadCounter()" is used to display the current score in Home page. Now what I want is : when the user restart the game, the current score (7)within sharedPreferences should be automatically reset to "0" so that the new score is added to 0 EX: 0 + 10 (new score) = 10 (will be in SP), and displayed in Home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by creating this function `unloadCounter()` and call it in `onTap(){}` or `onPressed()` of where I want to use it.

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.remove('counter');
  }
```